# Count the number of items in a dict

Tags: javascript

I have a simple problem, but the solution is not simple for me.
Basically I do have an array with status objects in it.

```
status = [ {status:1, id:10},
           {status:2, id:11},
           {status:1, id:12}]
```

I want now to count all objects with status 1, all objects with status 2 in one go. So my end result should be something like this:

```
[ [1,2], [2,1]]
```

I do already have this, but the latest step fails always for me:

```
items = status.map(function(x){return x.status})
unique = new Set(items)
```

And then I am stuck.

In python I know how to do it, but that is not an option at this moment.

```
// this is the python code 
items = [x["status"] for x in status]
[ [x, items.count(x)] for x in set(items)]
```

Comment: Does it need to be an array as a result? You can easily use reduce to accomplish such and, to me, it would make sense to return an object instead: https://jsfiddle.net/5ks9ph1n/

Comment: An object is also fine :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and an array of the key/value pairs with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

BTW, you need to rename a global `status` to something other, because [`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) is a string a reserved for status messages of the user agent.

```js
var array = [{ status: 1, id: 10 }, { status: 2, id: 11 }, { status: 1, id: 12 }],
    result = Array.from(array.reduce(
        (m, { status }) => m.set(status, (m.get(status) || 0) + 1),
        new Map
    ));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `status.reduce is not a function`

Comment: @Durga, where do you get the error? the inner `status` is a local variable, the outer is an array.

Comment: In chrome. After changing outer status to something else, it works.

Comment: @NinaScholz running the example gives the error. http://prntscr.com/msz37f Though the solution is absolutely fine, it throws TypeError

Comment: maybe a renaming helps.

Comment: just add `const` (or `var`) before `status` in the very beginning.

Comment: @NinaScholz renaming `status` to `array` fixes the issue. That's weird, in any other fiddle it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const status = [
  {status:1, id:10},
  {status:2, id:11},
  {status:1, id:12}
];
const statuses = [];
const result = [];

status.map(s => {
    if (statuses.indexOf(s.status) === -1) {
    result.push([ s.status, status.filter(i => i.status === s.status ).length ]);
    statuses.push(s.status);
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple `reduce` then use the entries to get your expected format :)

```js
const status = [ {status:1, id:10},
           {status:2, id:11},
           {status:1, id:12}];
           
const result = status.reduce((acc, {status}) => (acc[status] = (acc[status] || 0) + 1, acc), {});
console.log(result);

const formattedResult = Object.entries(result)
console.log(formattedResult);

// If you need to remove the string format from the keys: 

const formattedResult2 = Object.entries(result).map(([k,v]) => [Number(k),v]);
console.log(formattedResult2);
```

Comment: The output is not an array of arrays as described in the question.

Comment: Updated. Though, the expected output is quite unnatural to me!

Answer (score 0):

Since an object is an accepted answer as well (as stated in the comments above), you may also just use `reduce` and wrap data in a new object:

```js
var arr = [ {status:1, id:10},
           {status:2, id:11},
           {status:1, id:12}];
           
console.log(
   arr.reduce((a, {status}) => {
   if (a[status]) a[status]++;
        else a[status] = 1;
        return a;
  }, {})
)
```

You can still reduce the steps to accomplish stuff, though the above is quite easy to read. if in "a" (which is the empty object at the beginning) the status already exists, then increase it. Otherwise, set it to one and continue until the array is entirely looped.

`{status}` (the second parameter) gets the `status` key value of the currently looped object, equivalent of `item.status`.